# How to Convert M to m in date php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to convert the date like this

```
$original_date = date("M/d/Y"); // the output of that is Aug/27/2013
```

to "08/27/2013"

Comment: by typing lower case **m** ??!?

Comment: `$originalDate = date("d/m/Y");` Or is that too easy? Have I missed something?

Comment: Because he obviously has the date in that format, not generating it himself...

Comment: *obviously* is a matter of opinion. I and many others think he is showing code he has. in which case case all he has to do is change M to m

Comment: Is it bad i'm just giggling to myself at the question title :(

Comment: @Dagon So the answer would be what - turn off CapsLock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime($original_date));
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can convert pretty much anything reasonable you give it into a Unix timestamp, even stuff like "Next Friday".

EDIT

Funny, but seems that strtime doesn't work with a date formatted like that... The first thing that came to my mind was to replace those slashes with spaces, using str_replace or implode/explode or whatever works for you...

```
$newDate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', ' ', $origDate)));
$newDate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime(implode(' ', explode('/', $origDate))));
```

Comment: the output of that is 01/01/1970

Comment: Then your $original_date is wrong/false.

Comment: this is my code
    $newDate = date("M/d/Y");   
    $date1 = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($newDate));
    print_r($date1);

Comment: Give me a min to check, this was from the top of my head.

Comment: Crazy, it doesn't work with that. You can always do something like: `$date1 = date('m/d/Y', strtotime(implode(' ', explode('/', $newDate))));`

Comment: Cheers, mate! I learned something new as well.

Comment: makes no senses to convert $newDate; absolutely no need

Comment: `$newDate = date("M/d/Y"); $date1 = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($newDate)); print_r($date1);` EXACTLY THE SAME RESULT AS `$newDate = date("M/d/Y"); $date1 = date('m/d/Y'); print_r($date1);` and why use print_r for a string

Comment: And what if you don't generate the original date yourself, but get it from the database or wherever and get the string "Aug/27/2013"?

Comment: You're too rude for me to even continue discussing, have a nice day.

Comment: you are clearly not answering the  question, you are answering what you *think* the question is. And thanks, I plan to :-)

Comment: Shomz is right Im getting it from database which has a hundred records and still counting. i will consume too much of time if im going to change it one by one. plus im going to change the code wherein it insert date with M.

Comment: then use the db date functions far more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Simply by passing it back to the date function

```
$original_date = date("M/d/Y");

$new_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($original_date));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the format string:

```
$originalDate = date("m/d/Y"); // = 08/27/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetme) and specify the input format to avoid ambiguity:-

```
$dateString = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M/d/Y', $origanalDate)->format('m/d/Y');
```